# How to select one value that populates two values in a sealed class

Tags: c#

I have a sealed class and in this sealed class I have a "public int shoebox128bit { get; } = 256 / 8;" that gets entered in a byte array. Now, what I'm trying to do is when the user selects "shoebox128bit". I also need to enter a different value in one another byte array. In essence, I need to double the size.

```
RNGCryptoServiceProvider().GetBytes(shoebox = new byte[shoebox128bit]); // 32

byte[] shoeboxTools = new byte[shoebox128bitDoubled]; // 64
```

I know this may seem a little confusing but all I'm trying to do is when you select one value that it places that value in a designated spot in the class. Then, that value is doubled and entered that doubled value in another spot in the same class.

1. User selects shoebox128bit.

Behind the scenes in the class this action happens:

```
"32" in the RNGCryptoServiceProvider
byte[] shoeboxTools = new byte[64];
```

Is there a way to achieve this goal?

Thank you for your assistance in advance.

Comment: I don‘t exactly know, what you really need, but maybe you could use an Extension-Method, to achieve the desired target.

Comment: Do you need to return a doubled value of the initial value of `shoebox128bit` property every time the code access this property? For example, first access leads to return value `32`, second access - `64`, third access - `128`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I understand correctly, your sealed class is just a collection of, basically, constants?
Is your example also in the sealed class, or somewhere else?

The first thing that comes to my mind is to expand the property to execute code when the getter is called.
Like this:

```
private int _shoebox128bit = 256/8;    
public int shoebox128bit 
{ 
   get
   {
      shoebox128bitDoubled = _shoebox128bit * 2;
      return _shoebox128bit; 
   } 
}
```

This way each property can be in charge of the action that needs to happen on the related one.
Alternatively, you could make shoebox128bitDoubled into a kind of calculated property.

```
public int shoebox128bitDoubled => shoebox128bit * 2;
```

If the second property to get is always the same one, but with a different value based on the selection, you're probably better off with option 1.

Comment: Thank you Gamingdevil. This was very helpful to achieve that goal.